# Ударение в слове "лассо"

Tags: фонетика

Какое ударение в слове "лассо" (аркан для ловли животных): лАссо или *лассО*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ударение на последний слог: лассО.

Слово-то простое, достаточно в любой словарь заглянуть.

Comment: Большая просьба: заметки от себя пишите в комментариях, а в ответах - только по существу вопроса. Спасибо.